# Error fitting images into Conv2D layer in tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am building a CNN in keras, and am having trouble inputting my data.

My images are in the shape (-1, 40, 52, 1). I've tried fitting them through the inputLayer layer (which also requires 4 dimensions, but that ends up giving my conv layer a 5D input.

```
...
train_images.reshape(-1, 40, 52, 1)
test_images.reshape(-1, 40, 52, 1)

#Model
num_classes = 10
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[1,40,52,1]))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding ='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5, padding='same'))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()


#Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data= 
(test_images, test_labels), verbose=1)
```

I am looking for a way to fit my images through. But when I run this, I get the error:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 1, 40, 52, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback, but I settled for an alternative approach.

The 1-D array was split into 2, and made into a 2D "image," like so:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Instead of:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This reshaped my database from

> -1, 40, 52, 1

To:

> -1, 2, 26, 1

So i then just fixed my input layer:
`model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[2,26,1]))`

Answer (score 1):

You need not to add `batch_size`:

```
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[40,52,1]))
```

Comment: I've tried that. All that does is raise another error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 40, 52)

Comment: @JohnDoe Your `train_images` is not `(?,40,52,1)`. What's the shape of `train_images`?

Comment: When i run train_images.shape i get (1, 40, 52)

Comment: @JohnDoe So your input need to be adjust to (?,40,52,1).Your model have no problems.

Comment: @JohnDoe Re-assign the result of `reshape` back to `train_images` and `test_images` like this: `train_images = train_images.reshape(-1, 40, 52, 1)`.